# What is launchpad's I2C & SPI voltages?

Tags: voltage, spi, i2c, texas-instruments, launchpad

Does anyone know what voltages TI Launchpad's I2C and SPI run at?

I think it is 3V3 from a comment on a post, but can't be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SPI IO are relative to the supply voltage.  This may be from 1.8 to 3.6V for a typical Stellaris controller [MSP430F20xx](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430f2002.pdf) around page 24.

The LaunchPad development board [LM4F120](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spmu289c/spmu289c.pdf) has the Port 1 pins connected directly to the GPIO pins so there are no voltage level shifters so the voltage range should track the processor supply which is 3.3V.

I have never used one but this is what Google offered so may have missed some variations.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet will be getting the chip's datasheet. When unsure, the datasheet is your friend. You're looking for terms like *I/O Voltage Levels*, *Absolute Maximum Ratings*, and so on.

If the chip only has one supply voltage, the logic levels will equal to that.

Comment: TI Launchpad is an evaluation board, not a raw chip, so the chip datasheet will do little good except to tell you which power pins run the I/O.